# Retrieving uploaded photos by others to my wall

Tags: facebook, get, photos

I'm developing a Facebook app (game), which uploads photos using "me/photos". On the app page, I wish to display a little timeline of the photos uploaded by the app and their source is my friends (not me). When using FQL on the  table

```
SELECT post_id, message, description, type
FROM stream
WHERE filter_key = 'others' AND source_id = me() AND app_id = MY_APP_ID
```

I get the relevant posts but no Urls to the photos. No join I’ve tried to any other table seems to work. I did extend my access token to include the friends_photos privilege…
Would be grateful for any input.

Answer (score 0):

To get the photos request the 'attachment' field.

If you only wanted to get posts with photos, you could rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT post_id, message, description, type, attachment
FROM stream
WHERE filter_key = 'others' AND source_id = me() AND app_id = MY_APP_ID 
  AND attachment.fb_object_type = 'photo'
```

The url to the photo is available at `attachment.media.src`